# QGLViewer.vcxproj - The attribute "Include" in element <QtMoc> is unrecognized

Tags: qt

I want to build [libQGLViewer](http://libqglviewer.com/installWindows.html) with Visual Studio 2017 (v15.6.5). I have already installed Qt v5.10.1 and latest extension for Visual Studio 2017.

Please help me! I got an error message after loading the **libQGLViewer-2.7.1.pro**:

```
QGLViewer.vcxproj : error  : The attribute "Include" in element <QtMoc> is unrecognized.
```

Here are lines of `<QtMoc>` inside the **QGLViewer.vcxproj**

```
<QtMoc Include="camera.h" ConfigName="Release|x64" />
<QtMoc Include="camera.h" ConfigName="Debug|x64" />
<QtMoc Include="frame.h" ConfigName="Release|x64" />
<QtMoc Include="frame.h" ConfigName="Debug|x64" />
<QtMoc Include="keyFrameInterpolator.h" ConfigName="Release|x64" />
<QtMoc Include="keyFrameInterpolator.h" ConfigName="Debug|x64" />
<QtMoc Include="manipulatedCameraFrame.h" ConfigName="Release|x64" />
<QtMoc Include="manipulatedCameraFrame.h" ConfigName="Debug|x64" />
<QtMoc Include="manipulatedFrame.h" ConfigName="Release|x64" />
<QtMoc Include="manipulatedFrame.h" ConfigName="Debug|x64" />
<QtMoc Include="qglviewer.h" ConfigName="Release|x64" />
<QtMoc Include="qglviewer.h" ConfigName="Debug|x64" />
```

Note: Long time ago, I built the libQGLViewer with Qt v5.9.2 and older version of Visual Studio 2017, and everything was working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something wrong with Qt version 5.10.1. I don't know what exactly it is, but there is no such problem with Qt version 5.9.4. Everything is fine with 5.9.4.